# Inline Script tags/JQuery in Ektron

Tags: jquery, ektron

I'm trying to drop in a call to google-jquery and some inline script/style tags in ektron. I'm new to the CMS, is this even possible? Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#accordion-js').find('h2').click(function(){
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
            }).next().hide();
        });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#accordion-js').find('h2').toggle(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#04396D");
    $(this).css("background-image","url('101_up.png')");
    $(this).css("background-position", "center right");
    $(this).css("background-repeat","no-repeat");
    $(this).css("color","#FFF");
    }, 
function(){    
    $(this).css("background-color","#f4f4f4");
    $(this).css("background-image","url('101_down.png')");
    $(this).css("background-position", "center right");
    $(this).css("background-repeat","no-repeat");
    $(this).css("color","#777");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to do. It looks like you have successfully included jquery and are using it.

Is your question how to use the above code to create a toggling accordion in Ektron?

To use the above code, just place it in your ASPX template and it will run as in any webforms application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to generate an accordion from CMS content, there are a number of additional steps you will need to take to retrieve the content onto your page.

**Step 1**: Create an aspx template page, and to place that javascript code onto it

**Step 2**: Drop a repeating control like the asp:repeater onto your template. There are many tutorials available on this. A simple example is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx

**Step 3**: Databind a list of ektron content to your repeater. This code would look similar to the following:

Aspx Markup:

```
<div id="accordion-js">
  <asp:Repeater ID="myAccordion" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <h2>Content Title:<%# Eval("Title") %></h2>
      <p>Content Body:<%# Eval("Html") %></p>
    <ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Aspx.cs Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //create a content manager to interact with the CMS
  Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content.ContentManager cCRUD = 
   new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content.ContentManager();
  //create a content criteria to select content meeting specified filtering criteria from the manager
  Ektron.Cms.Content.ContentCriteria contentSelector = 
   new Ektron.Cms.Content.ContentCriteria();
  //specify a filter - in this case, all content in folder '0' (the root)
  contentSelector.AddFilter(
   Ektron.Cms.Common.ContentProperty.FolderId,
   Ektron.Cms.Common.CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, 
   0);
  //get the list and set it as the source of our repeater
  myAccordion.DataSource = cCRUD.GetList(contentSelector);
  //bind the list to the repeater
  myAccordion.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

If you are doing this from the code behind. The alert box below can be as much code as you like.

```
JS.RegisterJSBlock(this, "alert('hello');", "MyAlertId");

JS.RegisterJSInclude(this, "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js", "GoogleJQuery1.7.");
```

Ektron includes it's own jQuery by default as well that might be worth tapping into.

A band-aid solution would be to use an HTML content block and paste the code in there and drop that onto the page using a Content Block control widget. Not the best way but it does get the job done today although no one will applaud your stellar solution.

What we have done to get around this is build a Widget that uses the code behind techniques to put code into the page. It uses a custom smart form and works for these emergency situations.

Good luck.